# PHP exec bash script

Tags: php, bash

I've written a bash script to take a screenshot and I want to launch it from a PHP page:

```
#!/bin/bash

screenshot="screnshot.png"
screencapture='/usr/sbin/screencapture -xC'

if [ `whoami` == 'root' ]; then
loginpid=`ps -ax | grep [l]oginwindow.app | awk '{print $1}'`
  launchctl bsexec $loginpid $screencapture $screenshot
else
  $screencapture $screenshot
fi
```

When I try to launch it from CLI it works as expected but when I try to launch it with PHP it doesn't work:

```
<?php
exec("bash /Users/giorgio/Desktop/src.sh");     
?>
```

What's the problem with this?

**EDIT:**

As you've suggested I've put the script into the PATH eviroment variable (I've edited .bash_profile).
Now I can launch the command directly from CLI but the problem launching it from PHP stays the same.

I've tried with those commands but neither of them seems to work:

```
exec("bash /usr/local/bin/screenshot.sh");
exec("bash screenshot.sh"); 
exec("screenshot.sh");
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've tried to run the following code to indagate on what is happening to the called script:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$integer;
exec("bash /usr/local/bin/screenshot.sh 2>&1",$array,$integer);     
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($integer);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

It returns int(133); don't know what it means.
P.s. I've also edited the shebang.

**EDIT 3:**

var_dump of $array returns this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(51) "dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart"
  [1]=>
  string(134) "  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO"
  [2]=>
  string(59) "  Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(95) "/usr/local/bin/screenshot.sh: line 11: 44948 Trace/BPT trap          $screencapture $screenshot"
}
```

Comment: From CGI context, "bash" might not be set in the environment. Alter the script's shebang to `/bin/bash`. Otherwise let us know, how it *"doesn't work."*

Comment: I've changed the sha-bang and it doesn't work either from the php script; I don't know how to be more specific on this because the script it's supposed to create a .png on the Desktop and when I launche the script from PHP it isn't created! Sorry, I'm a newbie on this!

Comment: What I meant is to alter the first line of the script to be executed (the one starting w/ `#!`). Editing `.bash_profile` is of no use either; it's not used in PHP-cgi. Please make full use of [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) diagnostics; examine the code in `$return_var` and the script's output. (Output redirection might be necessary; append `2>&1` to the command and you should see *something* in `$output`.)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I've done as you said and I get $output and $return_val now. However I don't know how to interpret them :(

Comment: Glad to have been of help (kinda). You can accept your own answer; this is possible here (in case you didn't know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was generated because OSX and MacPorts are incompatible with each other for those
libraries!

To solve this you have to edit as root the file /usr/pkg/sbin/envvars:

Just:

1. Comment out these lines

   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. Add this line at the end of the document

   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory where the bash executable is located is in the PATH environment variable... good odds that the web server environment has filtered this out.

Comment: I've edited the question including your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.